# Article "the" with numbers

Tags: articles

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> "People are giving up drinking by thousands."
>   "People are giving up drinking by the thousands."

Answer (score 1):

I see three errors in the sentence

> People is giving up drinking by thousands.

1. The word "people" is plural so "are" is required.
2. Idiomatically the singular "thousand" is used.
3. The definite article before "thousand" is needed.

So my rewrite is

> People are giving up drinking by the thousand.

Alternatively it could be rephrased as

> Thousands of people are giving up drinking.

Comment: I would use the plural form with the preposition _by_ (i.e., _by the thousands_). [So would a lot of other writers](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by+the+hundreds%2C+by+the+hundred%2C+by+the+thousands%2C+by+the+thousand&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cby%20the%20hundreds%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cby%20the%20hundred%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cby%20the%20thousands%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cby%20the%20thousand%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @J.R. there are statistics and damned lies. I say it the way I do, because of my native tongue. If you really want the plural *thousands* then omit the definite article.

Comment: I doubt this is the work of lying statisticians. I think this might be an [**AmE**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by+the+hundreds%2Cby+the+hundred%2Cby+the+thousands%2Cby+the+thousand&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=17)/[**BrE**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by+the+hundreds%2Cby+the+hundred%2Cby+the+thousands%2Cby+the+thousand&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=18) thing instead. (Actually, I wondered that even as I was typing my original comment.)

Comment: @J.R. it is not the statisticians who lie. The mistruth is either in the question that was asked, or the way the data is interpreted, or both. For example: **correlation** does not equate to **causation**.

Comment: I am not a native speaker, so I am baffled, but I would shoose to the variant without the article like "They are chiming in by thousands." What is the role of "the"?

Comment: @DmytroO’Hope - In American English, at least, it’s idiomatic. See [this page](https://ludwig.guru/s/by+the+thousands) for some examples. But if you want to see more examples without the _s_, as Weather Vane recommends, you can find plenty of instances of that form on [this page](https://ludwig.guru/s/by+the+thousand).

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope another way to say it is "People are giving up drinking **in their thousands**".